# c - how to open a selected file in explorer

Tags: c++, c, windows, visual-c++, cmd

Like in google chrome, when you download something you can click "open in explorer" or something and it will open exlplorer with that file highlighted.
I am going to write a program (probably a c cmd program) that searches for a file in a giver location, then I want to be able to click and open the file right from the program.
Is there another way you would recommend I do it? It doesn't have to be c or even a cmd program.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about c++, but VB and youtube will help me a lot :)

thank you Chris for the link!

```
ShellExecute(handle, "find", <fully_qualified_path_to_folder>, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

Thank you everyone else for the links as well!

Answer (score 2):

To open a folder **and select one or more items within the folder**, the `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems` function is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If your downloaded file path is say `downloadFilePath`

Then

```
Process.Start(downloadFilePath)
```

will do the right thing. Based on the Open Verb Path for the file extension it should launch the default application for the file extension

Comment: `Process.Start` is neither C nor a standard C++ function. Which language is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `CreateProcess()` function from WinAPI.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int wmain()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );
    //open C:\Windows in Explorer
        CreateProcess
        (
        TEXT("c:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\explorer.exe"),
        " C:\\Windows",NULL,NULL,FALSE,
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,
        NULL,NULL,
        &si,
        &pi
        );
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention what framework you are using so I will give you the Qt option that I use. This will work on windows or any OS that Qt supports. I use it in my Qt applications that I build with Visual Studio.

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl( QUrl::fromLocalFile( "myfile.xls" ) );
QDesktopServices::openUrl( QUrl::fromLocalFile( "myfile.doc" ) );
QDesktopServices::openUrl( QUrl::fromLocalFile( "myfile.txt" ) );
```

Documentation is here [QDesktopServices::OpenUrl](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopservices.html#openUrl) [QUrl::fromLocalFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qurl.html#fromLocalFile)

Answer (score 0):

The `system()` way of doing things:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("explorer /select,C:\\Windows\\notepad.exe");
    return 0;
}
```

Full list of [options to explorer.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510)

Comment: Thanks - this does work but it quickly flashes open a black command prompt, and looks really sketchy.